# Authenticate Spring Security from Server Side

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, registration

I have a Spring MVC web-app that uses Spring Security for authentication. I have a registration page and after the user successfully enters all the details I want them to be automatically logged in using the information they just entered. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting the [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object manually while processing the user details. Here is the code:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
Authentication a =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUsername, newPassword, grantedAuths);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(a);`
```

Where newUser and newPassword are two Strings with registered user's credentials